# Powershell Script copying file from yesterday to other folder

Tags: powershell

I'd like to copy `test.csv` from folders test1 to test2, only if the file has yesterdays timestamp on. The code I'm currently working with doesn't copy my file and returns:

> Not copying ...\Desktop\test1\test.csv

```bsh
$DestingationFolder = "...\Desktop\test2"
$EarliestModifiedTime = (Get-date).AddDays(-1)
$Files = Get-ChildItem "...\Desktop\test1\test.csv" -File
foreach ($File in $Files) 
{
    if ($File.LastWriteTime -gt $EarliestModifiedTime)
    {
        Copy-Item $File -Destination $DestingationFolder
        Write-Host "Copying $File"
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Host "Not copying $File"
    }
}
```

Expected: Copy `test.csv` only if it's timestamp is from yesterday

Actual: Nothing happens and get Not copying ...\Desktop\test1\test.csv returned

Comment: There is exactly *one* file that can match the path `..\Desktop\test1\test.csv` - what exactly are you looping over?

Comment: You had the same type of question using a batch file a day or two ago, what is the reason for doing this in multiple scripting languages.

Comment: In my test environment it worked as expected, moving it onto the server the date that returned for yesterday date was returning 'CScript' and other stuff. I was told it would be easier in Powershell.

Comment: Is the path "...\Desktop\test1\test.csv" valid? Try just "%userprofile%\Desktop\test1\test.csv"

Comment: Yes I've just added ... to make it shorter

Comment: the folder `"...\Desktop\test2"` does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's worth deleting the question or not but found this worked for me. Mentioned in the comments above, `...` is in my paths only to make make them shorter for the question.

```bsh
$DestingationFolder = "...\Desktop\test2"
$Files = Get-ChildItem "...\Desktop\test1\test.csv" -File
foreach ($File in $Files) 
{
    if ($File.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
    {
        Copy-Item $File -Destination $DestingationFolder
        Write-Host "Copying $File"
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Host "Not copying $File"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit.  PowerShell 5

You misspelled DestinationFolder and forgot to create the folder %userprofile%\Desktop\test2

```
$DestinationFolder = "%userprofile%\Desktop\test2"
If(!(test-path $DestinationFolder))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $DestinationFolder
}
$EarliestModifiedTime = (Get-date).AddDays(-1)
$Files = Get-ChildItem "%userprofile%\Desktop\test1\test.csv" -File
foreach ($File in $Files) 
{
    if ($File.LastWriteTime -gt $EarliestModifiedTime)
    {
        Copy-Item $File -Destination $DestinationFolder
        Write-Host "Copying $File"
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Host "Not copying $File"
    }
}
```